# Express won't send headers

Tags: node.js, express

I've done this from scratch and it still gives me an error...

I've run

```
express test
```

then

```
cd test && npm install
```

I've edited the app.js adding a route such this:

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  return res.send('{"a":3}');
});
```

Then I've run node

```
node app.js
```

And when I try to access http://server/test I get

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I'm using
Node v4.2.1, Express 2.5.8, npm 3.4.0.

This just happens with Express, if I create a simple server on Node I can use writeHead.

Comment: If you've done this from scratch, why in the heck are you using version 2.x?!?! It hasn't been updated since 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});`,you send all the response headers to the client,so you can not send header again.

Because `res.send` is the function of express's response object,I look the source code of this send function:

[image]

- chunk is what you send here : String('{"a":3}')
- `this.set('Content-Type', setCharset(type, 'utf-8'))` here express helps us concat our content-type with utf-8 so server needs to send header again

That is why you get the error.

Ps.
 Sorry for my bad english and I hope you understand what I try to explain.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand why it happens, it was driving me crazy =) The solution of course is to use setHeader as @TLJ says, but it is great to know why this was not working.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `res.setHeader`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  res.send('{}');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = "localhost";
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```